# Detect control's property change

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a **Xamarin Forms** application, on a content page of the base project.

In this page, I have a `StackLayout` which contains some **custom controls** (named `Accordion`), which have a `Binding Property` (**boolean**), allowing me to know if their content is `open` or `close`.

How can I detect which one of the accordions is **clicked** and close the accordions that are set to open?

I thought of adding a TapHandler for each accordion I have, but I was wondering if there is a better solution to achieve it.

(I am not interested in open the clicked one since my Accordion control has its own tap handler)

Thanks for your answer.

**EDIT:**

Accordion.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Accordion : ContentView
{
    public Accordion()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsOpen = false;
        Close();

        Indicator = Img;
    }

    //Elements

    //Some properties

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsOpenProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsOpen), typeof(bool), typeof(Accordion), false, propertyChanged: IsOpenChanged);
    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty AccordionContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AccordionContent), typeof(View), typeof(Accordion), default(View));
    public View AccordionContent
    {
        get => (View)GetValue(AccordionContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(AccordionContentProperty, value);
    }

    //Open handling

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsOpen = !IsOpen;
    }

    public static void IsOpenChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if(bindable != null && newValue != null)
        {
            var Control = (Accordion)bindable;

            if(Control.IsOpen == false)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control, "Open");
                Control.Close();
            }
            if(Control.IsOpen == true)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control, "Closed");
                Control.Open();
            }
        }
    }

    public uint AnimationDuration { get; set; } = 250;
    public async void Open()
    {
        _content.IsVisible = true;
        await Task.WhenAll(
            _content.TranslateTo(0, 0, AnimationDuration),
            Img.TranslateTo(-20, 0, AnimationDuration),
            IndicatorOpen(),
            _indicator.RotateTo(0, AnimationDuration),
            _content.FadeTo(30, 50, Easing.SinIn)
            );
    }
    public async Task IndicatorOpen()
    {
        Img.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, -10, 0);

        return;
    }

    public async void Close()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(
            _content.TranslateTo(0, 0, AnimationDuration),
            Img.TranslateTo(10, 0, AnimationDuration),
            IndicatorClose(),
            _indicator.RotateTo(-180, AnimationDuration),
            _content.FadeTo(0, 50)
            );
        _content.IsVisible = false;
    }
    public async Task IndicatorClose()
    {
        Img.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

        return;
    }
}
```

`TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` is the method called by TapHandler when the accordion's head is clicked.

Comment: why not add a custom event to your Accordion control that is fired when it's state changes?

Comment: @Jason As I said i already have a method/event that opens the SINGLE accordion when clicked. What I want is to close all the other accordions

Comment: then have your page subscribe to that event and when it fires it should close the other controls.

Comment: ok maybe i am not understanding... I'll post the Accordion class

Comment: I'm suggesting that the control FIRE a custom event when it's open/close state changes.  The page subscribes to that event and then calls the Close() method of the other accordions.

Comment: oh so you are talking about an event handler ?

Comment: the control will fire an event, the page will assign a handler to respond to that event

Comment: Yeah, I know. Thanks for your answer and time

Comment: What you want is always keeping only one accordion is open?